# How to download file using Storage facade of Laravel in non ASCII characters?

Tags: php, laravel, filenames, laravel-storage

I am trying to download a file using Laravel's `Storage::download()` method but in many cases the file name is in Japanese characters. However in such cases Laravel throws error of `The filename fallback must only contain ASCII characters.` This error is thrown by this file: `/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/HeaderUtils.php`
So, how can I download file using Storage facade of Laravel in non ASCII characters?

Comment: It would appear that you can't.

Comment: hi, this was [an issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/25095) a while ago. since the file is in non-ascii names which some browser might wont support (looks at IE in compatibility mode), you have to provide an alternative name for the [`Storage::download()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Routing/ResponseFactory.php#L159), something like `Storage::download($myFile, 'my-ascii-file-name.filetype')` might solve your trouble. hope it helps. tbh, for best experience and backward compatibility, i'd avoid non-ascii on file names.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Google Drive allows file to download file in Japanese characters... Maybe there is some kind of solution out there.

Answer (score 0):

make change in `src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.php`

in the function `public function response`

instead of `$disposition = $response->headers->makeDisposition($disposition, $name ?? basename($path));`

add next:

```
$filenameFallback = Str::ascii(basename($path));
$disposition = $response->headers->makeDisposition($disposition, $name ?? $filenameFallback, $filenameFallback);
```

for more information click [here](https://github.com/consatan/framework/commit/1547d2979bd707da67c562b3abbdc7720217ba71)